# How can I make eclipse's autoformatter ignore a specific file type?

Tags: eclipse, format

Is there a setting in the `eclipse-formatter.xml` that I can use to ignore certain file types? e.g. `.sql` files.

Comment: What is `eclipse-formatter.xml`? Standard Eclipse formatter as configured in the Preferences.

Comment: The XML is generated using the values in the Eclipse Preferences and allows you to share settings across projects / workspaces. e.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xwiki/xwiki-commons/master/xwiki-commons-tools/xwiki-commons-tool-verification-resources/src/main/resources/codestyle-eclipse-java.xml

Comment: That example file only contains org.eclipse.jdt formatter settings - which are only used for Java files. Each editor which supports formatting has separate settings.